# How do I embed a Gecko or FireFox browser into a VB.NET application?

Tags: vb.net, firefox, windows-7, windows-vista, gecko

I am having some problems trying to embed Gecko or Firefox into my VB.net application - specifically when running on Vista or Windows 7.  Is this possible to do?  Or should I look for a different alternative?

Any links to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be using the [Mozilla ActiveX control](http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm) for that.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't there a problem using ActiveX control with Vista and Windows 7?

Comment: I just tried 1.7.12 on Vista 32-bit and it worked as far as I could tell

Comment: My site is not rendering properly when I access it from deployed server, while it is being shown and rendered properly when I used it on development system. Please help me how solve this problem. I have been trying to find the solution for a long time but failed.